# Old Clash of Clans account transfered - how to create a new village?

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

I have worked with Supercell to transfer my kid's CofC village from my GameCenter account to his. (He had started playing on my machine under my account but he now has his own account.) That is now resolved.

However, since he used to play on my machine, his village is still the one that loads when I launch the CofC app. It's not attached to my GameCenter account, but it's still the one that appears by default. Obviously, I don't want to play my kid's village (and in fact I can't even launch the app when he's playing on his side). How can I start a new village and link it to my GameCenter?

I'm thinking that a possible course of action would be to (1) backup, (2) restore to factory settings, (3) login to GameCenter and create a new village, (4) restore from backup. This should work but it's a bit involved. Anything easier?

Comment: I've voted to keep this one open, as we have very few actual authoritative Q/As on here regarding CoC.

Comment: @Tetsujin Me too, We need a champion to ask and answer the general questions so we can all close things under the normal rules of (too broad / too unclear / duplicate) rather than wielding the "all COC questions shall be closed" club.

Comment: This is a great thread as well on digging up which GC accounts were used with a specific app: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192541/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-all-your-game-center-accounts

Answer (score 2):

Solution found: download CofC on another device using the same GameCenter account (my iPhone), create a village on that device, go back to the iPad and CofC offered to load my newly created village. Problem solved.

Comment: I can confirm this. I had to borrow a friends iPad who did not play CoC. Then I made a new Apple ID. Signed in on the new iPad (to store and Game Center), played through the tutorial. Then I signed in to the same new Apple ID on my iPad and it asked if I wanted to overwrite with the new town hall 2 base I had just made

Comment: Simply making a new Apple ID and signing in on an existing iPad and then opening coc doesn't help. It actually permanently links the brand new Apple ID with the village that was played on the iPad before. A virgin device is required