# How do you get a list of all your Game Center accounts?

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

I need to know what the original account was for my Clash of Clans is so I may transfer to another device. Any suggestions? I have tried multiple times trying to find through my emails with no luck. Can Game Center email a list of my CoC account?

Comment: Please use tags relevant to the content of the question. For more information on tags, see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Can Game Center base it off the user name in a game?

Answer (score 1):

The Gamecenter tokens are saved in your keychain.

Open it in search for it (Game). It will list all accounts you have.

```
com.apple.account.AppleID.appleid-token-gamecenter
```

[image: game]

Comment: How do you find these tokens? I am also having a problem where i know my account exists and i have the name but i don't know the ID info or password. I tried to check all my emails but there weren't any results.